# Difference between Oracle ADF's AppModuleLocal and AppModuleShared

Tags: jakarta-ee, oracle-adf

In simple terms, can someone please explain to me the difference between the two application module instances created in ADF for every application, i.e *AppModuleName*Local and *AppModuleName*Shared? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37975_01/web.111240/e16182/bclookups.htm#ADFFD1590):

Shared App Modules make the same data (VOs) available across multiple user sessions without creating multiple instances of the App Module itself. Local app modules are separate, individual app modules, local to a given user session.